# Changing printer settings via command line

Tags: pdf, printing, command, line

I have a `Brother PT-9800PCN` label printer that uses 6mm to 36mm tapes.
Is there a way of changing the default paper size (width, length, orientation) via command line? 
I'm generating 18x113mm and 24x50mm labels in pdfs using fpdf and when sending the pdfs to the printer via php it only prints on what paper size is set as default.
I've tried commands with Adobe, Foxit and Sumatra.
I've also tried Verypdf pdfprint command line that has the option to set the paper size with the same outcome.
Was thinking that if I change via command line the default paper size and then send the print job it should work.

Comment: You may get a better response by asking this in `SuperUser`.

Comment: and how do I do that?

Comment: At the top menu bar in this page, click stackExchange drop down list (top left hand side), select SuperUser.

Comment: I have posted an answer here : http://superuser.com/questions/1050034/changing-printer-settings-via-command-line/1050161#1050161

Answer (score 2):

Export:

```
RUNDLL32.EXE PRINTUI.DLL,PrintUIEntry /Ss /n "printer" /a "C:\A4-format.dat"
```

Import:

```
RUNDLL32.EXE PRINTUI.DLL,PrintUIEntry /Sr /n "printer" /a "C:\A4-format.dat"
```

Comment: This worked for me but I needed to pass the d flag to the store and restore commands so it only modified printer data. store: `RUNDLL32.EXE PRINTUI.DLL,PrintUIEntry /Ss /n "Printer Name" /a "a4-format.dat" d g` and restore: `RUNDLL32.EXE PRINTUI.DLL,PrintUIEntry /Sr /n "Printer Name" /a "a4-format.dat" d g r`